# Primefaces fileUploadListener is not invoking with websphere 8.5

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, websphere

I am using primefaces 4.0, JSF 2.2.
FileUpload is working with Apache Tomcat 7.0
but fileUploadListener is not invoking with websphere 8.5.
there is no exception in logs.

Solution is working fine with Tomcat 7.0
component is part of a omplete registration form. and I checked it with and without enctype="multipart/form-data" in form. problem remains same.

FileUpload Component:

```
<p:fileUpload auto="true"
fileUploadListener="#{PatientRegistrationBean.uploadFile}"
mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="uploadedFile1"   
sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="10" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/">
</p:fileUpload>
```

Command button:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnSave2" value="Save" process="@form" update="@form"
action="#{PatientRegistrationBean.savePatient}" >
</p:commandButton>
```

I have posted this question on primefaces forum, but no answer till date.

I have done all settings required in web.xml. And Solution is working perfectly on apache tamcat 7.0.

Problem resolved. I just put the filter configuration before servlet configuration in web.xml, and problem is resolved. :)

Comment: Did you give `<context-param>` entry in web.xml for PrimeFace FileUpload?

Comment: Check your server logs/browser developer console (especially the network tab) for any errors. Also make sure you're not duplicating JSF jars in your websphere installation

Comment: @kolossus no jar conflict

Comment: @Diganta All configurations are ok. as solution is working fine on tomcat 7.0

Comment: @BalusC kindly look into it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i fixed adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form (h:form) and the following lines to the JSF Servlet conf in web.xml.

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
<multipart-config>
    <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

This solution also works for JSF 2.2 h:fileUpload